# Is this an example of bad design?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I will start with my design:

```cpp
class IOutputBlock{
public:
    virtual void write(char *) = 0;
    virtual bool hasMemory() = 0;
    virtual void openToWrite() = 0;
};

class IInputBlock{
public:
    virtual bool hasNext() = 0;
    virtual IField *next() = 0;
    virtual void openToRead() = 0;
};

class MultiplicationNode : public OperationNode
{
public:
    MultiplicationNode(Node *l, Node *r);
    ~MultiplicationNode(void);
    virtual bool hasNext();
    IInputBlock * evaluate();
};


class IOBlock: public IInputBlock, public IOutputBlock{
    virtual void write(char *);     
    virtual bool hasMemory();
    virtual void openToWrite();
    virtual bool hasNext();
    virtual IField *next();
    virtual void openToRead();

};
```

Inside the evaluate method i need to create an `IOuputBlock` to write data in the block. 
I want the `MultiplicationNode` consumer just see method for iterate over the block (`IInputBlock` interface).
But ​​in the return of evaluate method, I have to perform a typecast.
Is this implementation correct? Or is it an example of bad design?
Can u suggest another design? Or maybe design pattern to help.

```cpp
IInputBlock * MultiplicationNode::evaluate()
{
    IOutputBlock *outputBlock = new IOBlock();
    //need to write to outputblock
    return (IInputBlock *)outputBlock;
}
```

I could also do this below, but I don't think it is right, because i was violation "program to an interface", and exposing unnecessary methods inside evaluate method from `IInputBlock` interface.

```cpp
IInputBlock * MultiplicationNode::evaluate()
{
    IOBlock *outputBlock = new IOBlock();
    //need to write to outputblock
    return outputBlock;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the evaluate method and read/write methods be separated? Because I'm under the impression you're trying to do both in the same method.

Comment: @rubber You'll probably want a virtual destructor on those interfaces.

Comment: In the evaluate method, I need to write in the block, through the IOutputblock interface. 
But I need to return an interface type IInputBlock, because consumers of MultiplyNode can only see methods to iterate over the data.

Comment: *'i was violation "program to an interface"'* - that final version of evaluate is much better... you're not exposing anything extra - the runtime type is `IOBlock` either way, and the caller is only given an `IInputBlock*` to it.  More generally, I don't think it's terrific design: lots of pointers with little clear ownership, and it's not intuitively obvious what `void*` `write()`'s returning, how it'd know the length of data, whether `openToWrite()` may fail (and presumably throw, but what?), whether to retry (and after how long) if `hasMemory` is `false`, who `delete`s `IField*`s...

Comment: @ppl: You are right! I do not put just for simplicity.

Comment: @Tony D: You are rigth about `void * write()`. I copied it wrong from my code. I edited the question. The interfaces (`IInputBlock` and `IOuputBlock`) are not quite ready.

Comment: _Or is it an example of bad design?_ Yes I think it is due to the need for casting (and I hope you won't really do a c-style cast anyway). Try composition over inheritance in this case. i.e. have separate instances of IInputBlock and IOutputBlock concrete classes. Also I like structs for pure interface 'classes', but that's just me.

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to separate read and write classes (even if underlying data is shared):

```
class WriteOnlyBlock: public IOutputBlock{
    // return new instance of something like ReadOnlyBlock 
    // potentially tied to same internal data
    public: IInputBlock AsRead()...
}
```

This way you make conversion explicit and prevent callers from attempting to cast `IInputBlock` to  `IOutputBlock` and minimize number of extra methods exposed by each class.